# Contao 4.x /install.php returns 404

Tags: php, content-management-system, contao

After successful installation doesn't get the install.php.

> www.mydomain.com/web/contao/install.php

returns 404 error.Also I need a proper documentation for creating a custom module in contao.Someone please help me.

Answer (score 5):

First of all you need to set the DocumentRoot in your web server of your domain for your Contao installation to the `/web` folder of your Contao installation.

The route for the Contao Install Tool is `example.org/contao/install` in Contao 4 (without `.php`).

Documentation can be found here: https://docs.contao.org/

You can still create modules in Contao 4 the same way as in Contao 3, i.e. as an extension within in `/system/modules`. If you want to create a Contao 4 bundle, look at the documentation and look for other tutorials on the web and seek help in the community forums if necessary.